# PowerShell – ForEach folder in list, create shortcut and assign icon

Tags: powershell

first post here and complete beginner with PowerShell (and coding in general), so apologies if I'm missing something trivially obvious.

I have a text file with three columns (delimited by " : "). The first contains a path for a shortcut that I would like to create. The second contains the target path. The third column contains the path for the corresponding ICO file that should be applied to the shortcut.

I have been trying out various ways to phrase the code but my fundamentals are a bit too weak to really troubleshoot things effectively and so I'm mainly stumbling around in the dark. Here is what I thought would do the trick:

```
$Contents = Get-Content "D:\Projects\Learning To Code\PowerShell\Commands and Scripts\Shortcuts List.txt"
ForEach ($Line in $Contents) {

$ShortcutFile           = "`"" + "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment\" + $Contents[0].Split(":")[1] + ".lnk`""
$TargetFile             = "`"" + "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment\" + $Contents[1].Split(":")[1] + "`""
$IconFile               = "`"" + "D:\Miscellaneous\Other\Backend\Icons\" + $Contents[2].Split(":")[1] + ".ico`""
$WshShell               = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut               = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath    = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.IconLocation  = $IconFile
$Shortcut.Save()

    }
```

The contents of the "Shortcuts Lists.txt" are as follows:

```
Random Path 1\Name A – Title A:Random Path 2\Name A – Title A:Random Path 3\Name A – Title A
Random Path 1\Name B – Title B:Random Path 2\Name B – Title B:Random Path 3\Name B – Title B
Random Path 1\Name C – Title C:Random Path 2\Name C – Title C:Random Path 3\Name C – Title C
Random Path 1\Name D – Title D:Random Path 2\Name D – Title D:Random Path 3\Name D – Title D
Random Path 1\Name E – Title E:Random Path 2\Name E – Title E:Random Path 3\Name E – Title E
Random Path 1\Name F – Title F:Random Path 2\Name F – Title F:Random Path 3\Name F – Title F
Random Path 1\Name G – Title G:Random Path 2\Name G – Title G:Random Path 3\Name G – Title G
Random Path 1\Name H – Title H:Random Path 2\Name H – Title H:Random Path 3\Name H – Title H
Random Path 1\Name I – Title I:Random Path 2\Name I – Title I:Random Path 3\Name I – Title I
Random Path 1\Name J – Title J:Random Path 2\Name J – Title J:Random Path 3\Name J – Title J
Random Path 1\Name K – Title K:Random Path 2\Name K – Title K:Random Path 3\Name K – Title K
Random Path 1\Name L – Title L:Random Path 2\Name L – Title L:Random Path 3\Name L – Title L
Random Path 1\Name M – Title M:Random Path 2\Name M – Title M:Random Path 3\Name M – Title M
Random Path 1\Name N – Title N:Random Path 2\Name N – Title N:Random Path 3\Name N – Title N
Random Path 1\Name O – Title O:Random Path 2\Name O – Title O:Random Path 3\Name O – Title O
Random Path 1\Name P – Title P:Random Path 2\Name P – Title P:Random Path 3\Name P – Title P
Random Path 1\Name Q – Title Q:Random Path 2\Name Q – Title Q:Random Path 3\Name Q – Title Q
```

A bit more debugging has suggested that the root of the problem might lie with the Em Dash that's present in the shortcut path and target path for each line. Using the Write-Output $ShortcutFile command shows that the Em Dash gets replaced by ***`â€“***

Renaming all the files to replace the Em Dash isn't really an option so I'm hoping there's an alternative solution.

UPDATE: I've managed to circumvent the issue with Em Dash by replacing it with a unique string in the text file and adding a "-Replace" argument to the main code, but still no dice on the output. The Write-Output $ShortcutFile command shows that the code isn't going through line by line but just repeating the first line over and over. And I'm still getting the error telling me that the $Shortcut must end with ".lnk" or ".url"

Comment: Can you show us your `txt` file? I guess the format is incorrect. I'd recommend using `csv` files, because using them in powershell is quite easy. For debugging you can print the `$Line` in loop to check if it includes what you think it does.

Comment: Theoretically, that is a csv, and I would use `Import-Csv`, using `-Delimeter ":"`. This will turn all those rows into objects you can work with for a much easier experience

Comment: It is better to share a glimpse of your input file and desired output of your's . If you feel the data is sensitive, please sanitize your data before sharing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I've edited the original post to include the contents of the text file, and slightly modified the main code following a bit of debugging on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace those EM dashes with

```
$inputFile = "D:\Projects\Learning To Code\PowerShell\Commands and Scripts\Shortcuts List.txt"

(Get-Content -Path $inputFile -Raw) -replace '\p{Pd}','-' |
 Set-Content -Path $inputFile -Force
```

<sup>Regex `\p{Pd}` means "any kind of hyphen or dash"</sup>

Then it should be possible to use [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) on that

```
# define the COM object only once
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

# read and parse the CSV. Supply headers and define the delimiter used
$data = Import-Csv -Path $inputFile -Header 'Shortcut','Target','Icon' -Delimiter ':'
# loop through the data
foreach ($item in $data) {
    $ShortcutFile           = Join-Path -Path "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment" -ChildPath ('{0}.lnk' -f $item.Shortcut)
    $TargetFile             = Join-Path -Path "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment" -ChildPath $item.Target
    $IconFile               = Join-Path -Path "D:\Miscellaneous\Other\Backend\Icons" -ChildPath ('{0}.ico' -f $item.Icon)
    $Shortcut               = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath    = $TargetFile
    $Shortcut.IconLocation  = $IconFile
    $Shortcut.Save()
}

# finally remove the used COM objects from memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shortcut)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WScriptShell)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: The above code is working great, but it looks like there are still issues relating to the EM dash. When I copied the suggested code verbatim, the shortcut files were created but they failed to link to anything. Closer inspection revealed that the paths now contained regular hyphens instead of EM dashes (and so the Target Path was failing to find its target). When I manually overwrote the the -Replace argument and inputted an EM dash with Alt + 0150, the string containing the path substitutes the EM dash with a "?".

Comment: @AlexBoisot So, what are they then? Full paths like `X:\somewhere\MyShortcut.lnk` ? In that case, the delimiter will also split on the colon after the driveletter and that will not work unless all those paths are double quoted. Then of course you don't need the three `Join-Path` lines as you already have the complete path and filenames. Please give us a **sanitized** but workable example of the input file

Comment: @AlexBoisot Why would you want EM dashes or invisible control characters in there? These are not normal or even illegal in file paths. Did you use Word or something to create the input file? If you need to also remove invisible control characters, then also do a `-replace  '\p{Cf}',''`. For other characters outside the ASCII range that **are** legal (like umlauts), make sure you have saved the input file with UTF8 encoding.

Comment: I decided to run a test with all paths and filenames have only hyphens and no EmDashes and the code you offered ran flawlessly. I think I will just live with changing the naming convention, as I do not fully understand the implications of using special characters.

As an aside, is there a command to instruct the "View" settings of the shortcut folder to default to "Extra Large" icons? The source (target) folder is already set up with this view setting, but for some reason they are not carried over when accessing the location through the shortcut.

Comment: Update: I've managed to get the code running perfectly on a large number of files. Everything is working as intended, so thank you very much to all who helped!

One small issue I can't resolve: some of the paths contain commas in the string, and these generate errors when the code is executed. I thought I could solve this by just adding a backtick ( ` ) before each instance of a comma, but this doesn't work. What's the right way to escape the comma?

Comment: @AlexBoisot I don't think it's the comma, but there is no way of telling unless you show us some of the real strings you have in that file. Possibly quotes or (when typed in Word or from internet) these may even be those horrible curly 'smart-quotes'. The backtick won't help. As always, it would help if you tell us what the errors you receive are. We can't see your screen after all.

Comment: @AlexBoisot Check the input file. Make sure all fields are properly delimited by the colon `:`. If you have imported with added headers `'Shortcut','Target','Icon'`, then this line **`$ShortcutFile = Join-Path -Path "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment" -ChildPath ('{0}.lnk' -f $item.Shortcut)`** makes sure the `.lnk` is attached as extension. Also, in both your code as in mine, there is no `Write-Output $ShortcutFile` to be found. If you do put that in for testing purpuses, use `Write-Host` instead.

Comment: I don't have access to the data right now, but will have a look when I get back. The reason I'm convinced about the commas though is that the code worked perfectly for about 2,000 items, and the only ones that failed were ones where the filename contained a comma.

Comment: @AlexBoisot **please** show us such a filename then if you want to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: apologies for never marking your answer at the time! I was brand new to SO when I asked this question. Allow me to rectify this (even if two years late...). And thanks again for the patient attempts to offer help. The issue was ultimately resolved, in large part thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this how you want your data to be formatted? This is first line of your data, if this is right then it can be looped for other lines too and the shortcut can be created with the rest of your code.

```
$line = "Random Path 1\Name A – Title A:Random Path 2\Name A – Title A:Random Path 3\Name A – Title A"
$array = $line.split(":")
$array
$shortcutFile = "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment\"+$array[0] +".lnk"
$targetFile = "D:\Projects\PowerShell\Test Environment\"+$array[1]
$iconFile = "D:\Miscellaneous\Other\Backend\Icons\"+ $array[2]+".ico"

Write-Output $shortcutFile
Write-Output $targetFile
Write-Output $iconFile
```

Comment: Ah, no - should have clarified. The file names and paths have been sanitized for sharing. The actual paths are not formulaic as they appear in my post here.

Comment: @Alex Boisot, The first mistake I see in your code is $Contents[0].Split(":")[1] + ".lnk`. Here, it must be $Line instead of $contents(as you're using foreach). Since you have all the values separated by a ":" then each line must be converted to an Array from there you can pickup the values to form a desired path.